# Convert dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the next format:

```
a = {'file': {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [23, 134, 571, 13]}, 
     'file2': {'x': [1, 2, 3, 5], 'y': [123, 215, 21, 123]}}
```

Is it possible to convert this dictionary in this format (here keys are union between all x's):

```
{'1': {'file': 23, 'file2': 123}, '2': {'file': '134', 'file2': 215}, ..., 
 '4': {'file': 13, 'file2': '-'}, '5': {'file': '-', 'file2': '123'}}
```

I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't see where your 12 is coming from.

Comment: Whoops, should be 123. Edited.

Comment: where is `-` coming from?

Comment: If there is no y value for x, '-' should be placed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. I *think* what you want is something like:

```
interim = {k: {x: y for x, y in zip(v['x'], v['y'])} for k, v in a.items()}
```

which creates a dictionary mapping the `'x'`s to the `'y'`s:

```
{'file2': {1: 123, 2: 215, 3: 21, 5: 123}, 
 'file': {1: 23, 2: 134, 3: 571, 4: 13}}
```

then:

```
out_keys = set().union(*interim.values())
```

which creates the set of keys for the output:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

and finally:

```
output = {k: {k1: v1.get(k, "-") for k1, v1 in interim.items()} for k in keys}
```

which creates your output format:

```
{1: {'file2': 123, 'file': 23}, 
 2: {'file2': 215, 'file': 134}, 
 3: {'file2': 21, 'file': 571}, 
 4: {'file2': '-', 'file': 13}, 
 5: {'file2': 123, 'file': '-'}}
```

This is flexible such that any number of `'file'`s, `'x'`s and `'y'`s can be handled. Note that `zip` will truncate to whichever of the `x'`s and `'y'`s is shorter if they aren't the same length.

Comment: You mean `set().union(...)`? Also, that can just be `set().union(*iterim.values())`

Comment: @JonClements ah yes, that would be better - thanks; the `set(v) for ...` was only necessary because I called the method on the class, not an instance

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner, so to speak:

```
In [1]: %paste
a = {'file': {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [23, 134, 571, 13]}, 
     'file2': {'x': [1, 2, 3, 5], 'y': [123, 215, 21, 123]}}

## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: {x: {fkey: 
    ..:         ([y for _, y in zip(fval['x'], fval['y']) if _ == x] or ['-'])[0]
    ..:      for fkey, fval in a.items()}
    ..:  for x in set().union(*[fval['x'] for fval in a.values()])}
Out[2]: 
{1: {'file2': 123, 'file': 23},
 2: {'file2': 215, 'file': 134},
 3: {'file2': 21, 'file': 571},
 4: {'file2': '-', 'file': 13},
 5: {'file2': 123, 'file': '-'}}
```

Essentially it is equivalent to jonsharpe's answer, although it doesn't create an intermediate dict.